# Terraform: Get ID of resource output and use in root module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a load balancer security group inside a module. I'd like to reference that security group ID in another module in the root, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. I keep keep running into the following error:

> Error: Reference to undeclared resource
>
> on ecs.tf line 55, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_from_lb":
> 55:   source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg_alb.id
>
> module.concourse_web is a object, known only after apply
>
> A managed resource "aws_security_group" "sg_alb" has not been declared in the root module.

Here's my structure:

```
|_ modules
     |_ terraform-loadbalancers
          |_ sg.tf
|_ shared
     |_ ecs.tf
```

```
# sg.tf
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_alb" {
  name_prefix = var.name_prefix
  name        = var.name != null ? "${var.project}-${var.environment}-${var.name}-sg-alb" : null
  description = "Security group for ALB ${var.project}-${var.environment}-${local.name}-alb"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    ...
  }

  egress {
    ...
  }
}
```

```
# ecs.tf
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_ecs_instance" {
  name        = "sg_ecs_instance_${var.project}_${var.environment}"
  description = "Security group that is needed for the ECS instance hosts"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_from_lb" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  description              = "Allow traffic from load balancer"  
  from_port                = 8080
  to_port                  = 8080
  protocol                 = "TCP"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.sg_ecs_instance.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg_alb.id
}
```

The error is throwing me off, as I'm able to do something similar in other files, albeit with different resources.

What's the best way to reference `aws_security_group.sg_alb.id`?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/syntax - you are not actually using the module and the module does not have any outputs. Therefore: create outputs in the module and then actually use the module.

Comment: Thank you @luk2302. I do have an outputs file, not shown above. What I gather from the documentation is that only the calling file can access the outputs. Since this module is called by a different file, I need to do some refactoring.

Comment: @luk2302 I refactored, moving the contents of ecs.tf into the file that was calling the actual module, and that did the trick! The whole inherited thing was kind of a mess, but we've got it working. If you repost as an answer, I'll mark as accepted. Thanks!